# Display different errors react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a react application using redux.

In the redux store, let's say I have a book object with `title`, `isLoading`, `error`:

```
 const bookStore = {
  title: null,
  isLoading: false, 
  error: null
 }
```

I have two actions:

1. Fetch/GET book data from server
2. Update/PUT book title

In each action, I have to handle `isLoading` and `error`.

In the react component I can check (we ignore the loading for now)

```
 if (error) {return ErrorComponent}
 else return BookComponent
```

The thing is that I want to show the errors in different ways. If the request is GET (fetch data), I want to display error as ErrorComponent. If the request is PUT (update title) I want to display the error as a Toast.

How can I do that if I only have one error property in redux store?

Should I write the code like:

```
 const bookStore = {
  title: null,
  isLoading: false, 
  fetchError: null,
  putError: null
 }
```

But in this case I have to check like

```
 if (fetchError) {display ErrorComponent}
 else if (putError) {display Toast}
 else display BookComponent
```

It is kind of inconvenient. What would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can set `error` as an object
`error : { type: action.payload.type , value: action.payload.error}`

And your code will be :

```
if (error) {
     return error.type === 'error1' ? ErrorComponent : Toast; // or you can handle `toast` inside ErrorComponent  
}
else {  return BookComponent   }
```

Also, you can handle disply of error messages according to `type` you set in reducer.

Hope this helps!